# The term 'Select-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

I run the following commands:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-AzureRmAccount
WARNING: Because the Az modules have all the capabilities of AzureRM modules and more, we will retire the AzureRM
modules on 29 February 2024. Learn more about the migration to Az: http://aka.ms/azpsmigrate.

Account                                 SubscriptionName TenantId                             Environment
-------                                 ---------------- --------                             -----------
**.***@****.onmicrosoft.com                  e***-b4fb-0*** AzureCloud


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> az login --tenant "c*f"
You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "b**4",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Microsoft Azure",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "c**f",
    "user": {
      "name": "***@***.onmicrosoft.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionId "b**4"
Select-AzureSubscription : The term 'Select-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionId "b1597bc1-913e-4da7 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Select-AzureSubscription:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

but i got the above error any advice?
Thanks

**EDIT**

i run this command:-

```
  az login --tenant "c*f"
```

and i got this result

```
You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "b**4",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Microsoft Azure",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "c**f",
    "user": {
      "name": "***@***.onmicrosoft.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
```

but when i run this command:-

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "b**4"  -Tenant "c**f"
```

I got this result

```
WARNING: Because the Az modules have all the capabilities of AzureRM modules and more, we will retire the AzureRM
modules on 29 February 2024. Learn more about the migration to Az: http://aka.ms/azpsmigrate.
Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "b ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand
```

**EDIT-2**

I tried this command:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "b**4"  -Tenant "c**f"
```

but i got this error:-

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'Subscription' is ambiguous.
Possible matches include: -SubscriptionId -SubscriptionName.
At line:1 char:25
+ Get-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "b1597bc1-913e-4da7-a020-be3029 ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmSubscription], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMSubscriptionCommand
```

so i run this command:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "b**4"  -Tenant "c**f"
```

but got this error:-

```
WARNING: Because the Az modules have all the capabilities of AzureRM modules and more, we will retire the AzureRM
modules on 29 February 2024. Learn more about the migration to Az: http://aka.ms/azpsmigrate.
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'cfcab407-f59a-4db4-aec9-d5d3676d708f'
Get-AzureRmSubscription : Subscription b1597bc1-913e-4da7-a020-be30291a6494 was not found in tenant
cfcab407-f59a-4db4-aec9-d5d3676d708f. Please verify that the subscription exists in this tenant.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "b1597bc1-913e-4da7-a020-be30 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmSubscription], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMSubscriptionCommand
```

Comment: Select-AzureSubscription isn't a part of the AzureRM module.

Comment: @bluuf so how i can run `Select-AzureSubscription` in this case?

Comment: Best practice: install the new AZ module and then use Select-AzSubscription instead. The AZ module is the new Azure module (it can be a pain to install if you have the RM modules installed, I had to remove them all to prevent conflicts, but on the plus side: now I have all the Azure management tools available without getting weird conflicts)

Comment: Instead of using `Select-AzureSubscription`, please use [`Get-AzureRmSubscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermsubscription?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: @GauravMantri i tried this but i got an error `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "b**4"
WARNING: Because the Az modules have all the capabilities of AzureRM modules and more, we will retire the AzureRM
modules on 29 February 2024. Learn more about the migration to Az: http://aka.ms/azpsmigrate.
Get-AzureRmSubscription : Subscription b***4 was not found in tenant . Please verify
that the subscription exists in this tenant.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "b ...
+`

Comment: Does the subscription exist in the tenant you have specified?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes it do.. because when i run this command `az login --tenant "c*f"` i got the subscription , as follow `[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "b**4",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Microsoft Azure",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "c**f",
    "user": {
      "name": "***@***.onmicrosoft.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }]`

Comment: @GauravMantri which is `b**4`..

Comment: Let's start over :). Can you please update your question and include the latest code you're running and the output you're getting? Also, please use the first few characters of your tenant id and subscription id instead of "b**4". Thanks.

Comment: Aah...I should have seen this earlier. Can you try and use `Get-AzureRmSubscription` instead of `Select-AzureRmSubscription` (BTW, I am not able to find `Select-AzureRmSubscription`)?

Comment: @GauravMantri can you please check my second edit.. the `Get-AzureRmSubscription` did not work either

Comment: Hmm...That's weird. Can you try just running `Get-AzureRmSubscription` (i.e. without any parameters) and see the list of subscription ids and their respective tenant id returned by this cmdlet? See if you can find `b1597bc1-913e-4da7-a020-be30291a6494` subscription id in the result.

Comment: @GauravMantri the `Get-AzureRmSubscription` will not return any result..

Comment: I just tried the same commands with my Azure subscription and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below commandlet :

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription <SUBSCRIPTION> -Tenant <TENANTID>
```

Comment: i will get this error `Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "b***8e3 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand`

Comment: Sorry... give the subscription name
`Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "<SUBSCRIPTIONNAME>"`

Comment: you could run this `Get-AzureRmSubscription` - to get the list of subscription and subscription name

Comment: `Get-AzureRmSubscription` will not return any thing... but when i run this command `az login --tenant "c**f"`

Comment: i will get his:- `You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "b**4",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Microsoft Azure",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "c**f",
    "user": {
      "name": "mohannad.ghawi@tdmgroup.onmicrosoft.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: so i am able to see the subscription in the above command...

Comment: Did you try `Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "Microsoft Azure"` ?

Comment: C yes and i will get this error `Select-AzureRmSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command since -current is not correct parameter in the query

[image]

Comment: i will get the same error `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Select-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionId b***4
Select-AzureSubscription : The term 'Select-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.`

Comment: Can you check the azure command modules downloaded in your powershell  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0 and make sure you are running the powershell in admin mode

Comment: Skukla yes i am running using admin mode + the related modules are downloaded